# Which language/framework should be used for cross-platform software on Mac OSX and windows

Tags: cross-platform

I'm trying to write a software running on both of windows and Mac OS X. This is software is very similar as Dropbox's client. Below are the characteristics:

1. UI is not complex. Most of user operations is configuration and watch software's status
2. Need to talk with system to retrieve system's performance, for example the CPU's utilization, network bandwidth utilization …etc.
3. Use as less as possible system resource(CPU, memory, IO)

So my questions which language, framework I should to use. The language/framework should:
  1. The core code should can be reused on both of windows and Mac OSX on code level. Code level means the code can run on cross-platform, but I don't mind recompile code on each OS platform

1. The core code layer can very easy integrate with OS specific codes, for example Mac OS's cocoa objective-c code or windows's C++ code. The reason is I want to write two difference UI view layer by OS specific language.
2. That will be better if the codes can be compile to native instructions instead of interpretive instructions like Java. This is performance consider.
3. Again, as fast as possible, as small as possible.
4. I prefer LISP family, but not necessary.

Comment: More like the VB than Lisp, but Xojo creates native apps for Windows and Mac and seems to also meets your other requirements. http://www.xojo.com

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no simple and 'right-way' solution.

I believe it is good to use C++/C:

```
- you will have to use OS-specific API and code to 'talk to system'
- you would use QT, but you want to use 'as less as possible resources' - this is not about QT
```

It seems like it is not a big project. So, I think the better way is to develop it using C++ or even plain C (if you're good with one of them).

You can write OS specific code in separate functions/classes. Then write generic classes/functions to make an abstraction.

You can use #define's and #ifdef's to make it crossplatform (sure, you will have to recompile it for every platform).

I think this is the only way if you need to create crossplatform and really tiny application for MacOS & Win.

**UPDATED**

On LISP. First of all, it needs a LISP-machine. Even if you will compile it for Windows into EXE-file, it will not 'use as less as possible system resources' as you want.

And if it is similiar to Dropbox client, it should be running as a service/daemon - I think it is not a good choice to use LISP for such task.

Answer (score 0):

If you want small and cross-compiled, then C/C++ is your best friend as few other languages would be as efficient and fast. For a simple UI, you could use [C++/Tk](http://cpptk.sourceforge.net) and I think there are platform-specific projects for Tk like Tk-Cocoa etc.

But if you want to write cross-platform (i.e write once run everywhere), then look for Java Virtual Machine based languages. Note that JVM is fast and efficient, once it is up and running.

There are several Lisp-like languages for JVM, including JScheme and Clojure.